# LLDB - How do I print a value of global variable?

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

In my case, stack is not decoded correctly, so I can't use frame-related commands.
I'm trying to use some kind of absolute name to read variable from a specific module.

I was able to locate the variable:

```
(lldb) image lookup -s os::_mem_serialize_page libjvm.dylib
Address: libjvm.dylib[0x00000000009bd690] (libjvm.dylib.__DATA.__common + 151184)
Summary: libjvm.dylib`os::_mem_serialize_page
```

However, I don't understand how to read its value

```
(lldb) print os::_mem_serialize_page
error: use of undeclared identifier 'os'

(lldb) print libjvm.dylib`os::_mem_serialize_page
error: use of undeclared identifier 'libjvm'

(lldb) x/g libjvm.dylib[0x00000000009bd690]
error: invalid start address expression.
error: address expression "libjvm.dylib[0x00000000009bd690]" evaluation failed
```

**The only way I found**

Find address, approach 1

```
(lldb) image lookup -v -s os::_mem_serialize_page libjvm.dylib
Address: libjvm.dylib[0x00000000009bd690] (libjvm.dylib.__DATA.__common + 151184)
Summary: libjvm.dylib`os::_mem_serialize_page
 Module: <snip>
 Symbol: id = {0x0000e81e}, range = [0x000000010ee46690-0x000000010ee46698), name="os::_mem_serialize_page", mangled="_ZN2os19_mem_serialize_pageE"
```

Find address, approach 2

```
(lldb) image dump symtab libjvm.dylib
Index   UserID DSX Type            File Address/Value Load Address       Size               Flags      Name
------- ------ --- --------------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------------ ---------- ----------------------------------
[59422]  59422     Data            0x00000000009bd690 0x000000010ee46690 0x0000000000000008 0x001e0000 os::_mem_serialize_page
```

Read memory at address to get the variable's value

```
(lldb) x/g 000000010ee46690
0x10ee46690: 0x0000000000000000
```

But that's inconvenient because it takes multiple steps and I have to specify variable type myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had debug information for the symbol that you are trying to print, then your "print" attempts would have worked.  But it doesn't look like you have debug information for the library that has this symbol, or `image lookup -v` would have printed the defining compile unit.

You do have a symbol for it, however (which your `image lookup -v` command found).  So you should be able to print the value from the symbol.

Problem is if you give lldb the demangled name `os::_mem_serialize_page`, it's going to start off by trying to find "os" (so it can find _mem_serialize_page in that class or namespace.)  Since there are no types, it won't know anything about "os", and it will stop there.

But if you give lldb the mangled name lldb will look it up directly from the symbol table and it will be able to go from there to the address.  That will cut out one of the steps above.

However, there's no way around having to tell lldb the variable type.  Without debug information lldb has no way of knowing the type, and it can't really print the value w/o knowing that.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, I snipped module info from `image lookup -v`. Of course I have the debugging info, otherwise `image lookup -v` wouldn't find it. Symbol mangling is an interesting point. Do you know ho to get around that and convince LLDB to take the mangled name? Otherwise it's still a to-step process, which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: `image lookup -v -s` will look up symbol names as well as debug info, so the fact that it found `os::_mem_serialize_page` does not mean you have debug info for libjvm.dylib, or for this part of it in any case.  If you had debug info there would be have to be another entry for CompileUnit.  Did you snip that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Using a hint from `Jim Ingham` regarding `image lookup -v`, I figured that the variable could be read using its mangled name:

1. Identify the mangled name:

```
(lldb) image lookup -v -s os::_mem_serialize_page libjvm.dylib
<snip> name="os::_mem_serialize_page", mangled="_ZN2os19_mem_serialize_pageE" <snip>
```

2. From now on, this name could be used to read the variable

```
(lldb) p _ZN2os19_mem_serialize_pageE
(void *) $5 = 0x0000000000000000
```